# Unable to create XAML array of views with mvvm:ViewModelLocator

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I want to make a xamarin forms carousel view containing 2 custom views. I have this code:

```
<ContentPage x:Class="MainView" xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Views" x:Name="Main">
<CarouselView>
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
            <views:View1  mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference Main}" />
            <views:View2 mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference Main}" />
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
</ContentPage>
```

When launching the app, exception is thrown:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 80:37. Can not find
>   the object referenced by `Main`'

If I just set both views as direct content of the main page, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to make the collection of views through the MainViewModel?

Comment: I am not confident about your scenario. But where is the reference for Main? Is it in the MainPage? I don't find any view with x:name="Main"

Comment: Yes, <ContentPage class="MainView" x:Name="Main"> ... carousel ... </ContentPage>

Comment: `... make the collection of views through the MainViewModel...` - you do _not_ want to do that. Make a collection of view models instead and map to data templates.

Comment: And how do I map each view to their own viewModel in the carousel?

Comment: I guess what Haukinger said makes sense and regarding mapping the View to item. You could use a DataTemplateSelector. [MSDocs link for ItemTemplate selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime).
The API `ItemTemplateSelector` is not present in `CarouselView` as in `ListVew`. `ItemTemplate` itself takes DataTemplateSelector object.

Comment: Yes, use [datatemplateselector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplateselector?view=xamarin-forms) to choose item appearance at runtime and binding to corresponding model in itemSource.